# Using Rails 3 and Haml 3, how do I configure Haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3.0.0.beta3 and Haml 3.0.0.rc.2, and I can't find where I need to place the configuration lines for Haml (nor what they are in the new version, for that matter). Using Rails 2.3.5 and Haml 2, I would do

```
Haml::Template.options[:format] = :html5
```

in environment.rb. Or, in Sinatra,

```
set :haml, {:format => :html5}
```

in my main file. But in Rails 3 everything's been changed around, and no matter where I put that configuration line, I get an undefined method or undefined object error.

Answer (score 17):

Create the file:

```
#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/haml.rb
```

With haml option:

```
Haml::Template.options[:attr_wrapper] = '"'
```

Comment: This is absolutely the best way to do it in Rails 3… what about per-environment settings? If I want to have `:ugly` on only in Production?

Comment: +1, too bad you weren't picked as best answer since this is the best.

Answer (score 8):

In accordance with Rails 3's lazy-loading philosophy, Haml only initializes itself once `ActionView::Base` is loaded, which may not have happened when the configuration file is being parsed. In order to run code once Haml's been loaded, you need to run it in a `ActiveSupport#on_load` block. For example:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_vew) do
  Haml::Template.options[:format] = :html5
end
```

I'm considering ways of making the configuration accessible before the full Haml system has been loaded, either by defining `Haml::Template.options` earlier or adding a special `config.haml` hash.