# HAML create data-reveal attribute

Tags: angularjs, haml, zurb-foundation

Going off of Foundation docs, I'd like to have this line generated by HAML:

`<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal></div>`

How would I do that? Neither of the following two work:

`#myModal.reveal-modal{"data-reveal" => '' }`

`#myModal.reveal-modal{"data-reveal" => true }`

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726673/using-rails-3-and-haml-3-how-do-i-configure-haml

Comment: `#myModal.reveal-modal{"data-reveal" => true }` should do what you want (apart from the order of attributes). What are you getting for it?

Comment: It'd be `data-reveal=""` and I'd like to see `data-reveal`. Looks like a HAML configuration issue. The good news is that either way actually works with angular.js

Comment: As far as I know the only way Haml would generate `data-reveal=""` would be with `#myModal.reveal-modal{"data-reveal" => '' }`. Using `true` will generate either `data-reveal` or `data-reveal='data-reveal'` depending on the format.